# Convert polar complex number to cartesian

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to convert $e^{1+i(\pi/4)}$ into Cartesian form. Normally, I would use r and the arg to convert to $r(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta$) and I would be fine to go from there. The fact that there is a $+1$ in the exponent as well is throwing me off and I don't know where to start.

Comment: Start with $\,e^{a+b} = e^a \cdot e^b\,$.

Comment: Right, of course--exponent laws. Easy to get tunnel vision while working with complex numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$e^{1+i(\pi/4)}= e e^{i(\pi/4)} = e(\cos (\pi/4)+ i \sin (\pi/4))$$

Answer (score 0):

In general $e^z = e^{\Re(z) + i\Im(z)} = e^{\Re(z)}(\cos\Im(z) + i\sin \Im (z))$.

You should be able to apply this to your case.